# Как сохранить и выйти после изменения сообщения коммита?

Tags: git, git-commit

Как же мне не везет с *git* ( восьмой урок достал вот [здесь](http://githowto.com/ru/commiting_changes): сделал *git commit*, далее пишется "В первой строке введите комментарий: «Added h1 tag».

Сохраните файл и выйдите из редактора. Вы увидите…", написал «Added h1 tag»(нажав кнопку `INSERT`) а как сохранить и выйти?

Comment: Vim? 

ESC :wq

Comment: прямо на строке так написать?

Comment: Нет, нажмите кнопочку Escape (самая верхняя слева), а потом начните вводить :wq или ZZ

Comment: спасибо, получилось. интересно, Почему они туда не написали это же для начинающих.

Comment: А просто редакторы могут быть разные. Когда я установил под винду git, то редактором установился обычный notepad.

По поводу vim - в некоторых случаях бывает, что нажатие кнопки esc и потом `:wq` не приводит к желаемым результатам. В свое время увидел совет нажимать esc  в ответственных случаях дважды  (а в супер ответственных - три). Два нажатия гарантировано выводят в командный режим в 99.9% случаев. Лишнее нажатие не повредит.

Comment: очень интересно)

Comment: @1101_debian: после :wq ещё Enter надо. ZZ всегда прощё.

Comment: юзайте git commit -m "Added h1 tag" и будет счастье

Comment: @NickVolynkin, всё же не дубликат...

Comment: @Qwertiy почему? Вроде подходит.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>

По необходимости добавить <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Поступайте проще

```
git commit -m "Added h1 tag"
```

Comment: такой вариант не сработал, а решение ESC :wq, как выше ответил   1101_debian

Answer (score 2):

нажимаете последовательно:

```
Esc + Z + Z
```

при создании коммита можно не попадать в Vim написав комментарий в кавычках:

```
git commit -m "Added h1 tag"
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/181472