# Как выйти из редактора Vi или Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Работал в командной строке. Попал в странный текстовый редактор, в котором не работает мышка. Вижу сообщение

> "type :quit to quit VIM"

Но команда пишется прямо в текстовый файл и не выполняется.

Что делать, как выйти?

Comment: [Нет, но они требуют денег за его использование](http://i.imgur.com/cfKSC.png) И еще пасхальных яиц в догонку.

`:help 42
:help holy-grail
:help!
:help map-modes
:help UserGettingBored
:help spoon
:help showmatch
:Ni!
:help bar`

Comment: @igumnov: отличные пасхалки. Надо их в tag-wiki )

Comment: Анекдот: я очень много пользуюсь редактором vim. Главным образом потому, что не могу из него выйти :)

Comment: @o2gy: хе-хе :)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/5000805

Comment: Эх, надо было 1-го апреля писать...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в Vim!

Прежде чем ввести команду, **нажмите <kbd>Esc</kbd>**. Чтобы потом подтвердить команду, нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Клавиша <kbd>Esc</kbd> переключает Vim в [нормальный режим](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal). Если в этом режиме нажать <kbd>:</kbd> (проверьте, что установлена английская раскладка и снят CapsLock, затем одновременно нажмите <kbd>Shift</kbd> и <kbd>;</kbd>), то символ `:` появится в *нижней части экрана*, и редактор перейдёт в [режим командной строки](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line). Это гарантирует, что вы сейчас именно вводите команду, а не редактируете файл. Помните, что  регистр вводимых команд важен.

У большинства команд есть укороченные версии. Необязательная часть дается в квадратных скобках: `к[оманда]`.

Команды, данные *`курсивом`*, подходят только для Vim (не реализованы в Vi).

**Выйти безопасно (не срабатывает, если есть не сохраненные изменения)**

- `:q[uit]`  Выйти из текущего [окна Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window). Если это окно — последнее, то выйти из Vim. Если в текущем [буфере](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#buffers) есть не сохраненные изменения, команда не сработает.
- *`:qa[ll]`*  Закрыть все окна и выйти из Vim. Не сработает, если хотя бы в одном буфере есть не сохраненные изменения.
- 

**Выйти с подтверждением (запрашивает подтверждение, если есть не сохраненные изменения)**

- *`:conf[irm] q[uit]`* Закрыть все окна и выйти из Vim. Запрашивает подтверждение, если есть буферы с не сохраненными изменениями.
- *`:conf[irm] xa[ll]`* Сохранить все изменения, закрыть все окна и выйти из Vim. Запрашивает подтверждение, если какие–либо буферы не могут быть сохранены.

**Записать (сохранить) изменения и выйти**

- `:wq`  Записать текущий буфер в соответствующий ему файл (даже если изменений не было) и закрыть окно. *`:wqa[ll]`* для всех окон.
- `:wq!` То же самое, но записывает даже файлы, отмеченные только для чтения (read-only). *`:wqa[ll]!`* для всех окон.
- `:x[it]`, `ZZ`(но с некоторыми [особенностями](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#ZZ)). Сохранить файл *только если в нем есть изменения* и выйти, *`:xa[ll]`* для всех окон.

**Отменить (и потерять) изменения и выйти**

- `:q[uit]!` *`ZQ`* Выйти без сохранения, в том числе когда есть изменения в видимых буферах. Не сработает, если изменения есть также и в скрытых буферах.
- *`:qa[ll]!`*, *`:quita[ll][!]`* Выйти без сохранения, отменяя все изменения как в видимых, так и в скрытых буферах.

**Нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd> чтобы выполнить введенную команду.**

Этот ответ все-таки не охватывает все возможные способы выйти из Vim. Полный список можно найти в [документации Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:q).

На момент публикации все ссылки верны и ведут на англоязычную версию документации, но сайт временно недоступен. Когда он поднимется, я добавлю ссылки на русскоязычную версию.

Vim также имеет встроенную документацию. Чтобы ее открыть:  <kbd>Esc</kbd>`:help`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Чтобы использовать русскоязычную встроенную документацию, [необходимо включить русскую локализацию в настройках Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126853/2790048).

<sub>Это перевод собственного ответа [на EN.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30710567/2790048). При написании использовалась документация Vim и, в качестве ориентира и источника вдохновения, ответы других пользователей, особенно @dirvine.</sub>

Comment: А что делать если мой cmd не реагирует вообще на Esc ?

Comment: Можете помочь с моим вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654433/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-vim-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-esc-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B

Comment: Он и не должен реагировать на Esc, нажали несколько раз и вводите команду: `:wq` начиная с двоеточия вы будете видеть, что вводите внизу экрана.

Comment: @mymedia спасибо за правку!

Answer (score 4):

Выход **с сохранением изменений** в файле:

- Сначала жмем Esc
- потом :wq!
- потом enter

Если требуется выйти **без сохранения изменений**, то вместо :wq! надо написать **:q!**

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайте внимание, на уже данные ответы. Как вы думаете, если все, кто знает как выйти из vi здесь ответят, сколько уже в этой теме будет ответов?

Comment: Обсуждение на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9459/213987

Comment: @0xdb, в данном случае не считаю ответ дублем.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тема же на мете уже открыта, зачем комментарий? И я не писал, что это дубль, если бы это было так, то флаганул бы.

Comment: @0xdb, да, действительно тревога про дубль на ответе висит не твоя.

Comment: не является дубликатом, является краткой выжимкой другого ответа. возможно кому-то будет более подходящим. на мете тема больше про полные дубликаты, но конечно надо было задавать сразу по горячим следам, а не сейчас когда история не совсем такая и ссылок уже не найти.

Comment: Фраза "Сначала жмем Esc" приводит меня в уныние... Дело в том что эта кнопка у меня не нажиматся... А вот нашел... надо нажать Ctrl+C. Странно, что об этом ни слова... Да с плюсом тоже проблема... Нажал через NumPad. Хорошо, что у вас все кнопки жмутся. Значит вам повезло.

Comment: @Анатолий, если `Esc` не работает (или эта клавиша отсутствует на клавиатуре), то ввести тот же код можно и сразу, нажав `Ctrl+[`

Answer (score 3):

Выйдите лучше так:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> затем `:q!` и подтвердить <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Замените редактор, на тот, в котором выход не вызовет затруднений:

```
export EDITOR=notepad.exe
```

После чего, повторите комманду, после которой попали в "незнакомый" редактор.

---

И только если абсолютно уверены, то выйдите с сохранением изменений:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> затем `:х` и подтвердить <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: `export EDITOR=notepad.exe` - это юмор такой? Откуда блокнот на линуксе и как его запускать без вайна?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Почему юмор? Подозреваю, что ситуация более типична в git-bash под виндой и так будет работать. Метки linux тут нет. Хотя, может вы и правы, подумаю, и может заменю на `<мой редактор>`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Всё проверил на нетронутом Git-Bash (MINGW64_NT-6.3). Сделал новый проект на gitlab, после клонирования core.editor не установлен, поставил EDITOR=notepad.exe и сделал commit. Всё работает. Но если это выглядит как шутка, то может лучше оставить как сейчас, как вы считаете?