# Как выйти из Vim если Esc не срабатывает? Не включается режим ввода команды

Tags: windows, vim, vi

Я знаю, что при использовании vim , чтоб выйти с сохранением, нужно  нажать следующие кнопки, по одной: `<Esc>:wq<Enter>`

Я нажимаю на Esc и ничего не происходит, не открывается режим ввода команд

Вот так выглядит мой vim

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на `Esc` ничего не меняется и выглядит он также, нажимаю на `wq` я так понимаю, что внизу должны появиться эти буквы, но ничего не появляется, нажимаю `Enter` и опять ничего

Режим ввода команды просто не включается

Как это исправить? Что делаю не так?

Когда нажимаю `Ctrl + ]` получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажимаю `Ctrl + c` ничего не происходит

Comment: попробуйте комбинацию ctrl + c, ctrl + ]

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Добавил в вопрос

Comment: А обязательно текст в виде скриншотов? Текст в виде текста вообще никак?

Comment: *нажимаю на `wq`*. а где же двоеточие, о котором сами и упоминаете в начале? `:wq`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да действительно все дело в этом символе `:`

Comment: если уж пишите про *кнопки по одной* и уточняете нажатие *кнопки* `<Esc>`, то и про *кнопку* `<Shift>` не забудьте перед нажатием *кнопки* `;`.

Comment: А ещё есть команда `ZZ`

Comment: не много(совсем чуть-чуть) запоздало, но может кому в будущем поможет, не пытайтесь на английской раскладке наживать shift + 6(^), а не двоеточие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

программа *vim* может находиться в нескольких разных [режимах работы (mode)](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#vim-modes-intro).

из любого другого режима, нажав клавишу <kbd>esc</kbd>, можно вернуться в так называемый основной, умолчальный, «нормальный» режим (normal mode) (также встречается название «режим навигации»).

чтобы ввести **команду** (например, упоминаемую вами `wq` — «write and quit»), надо переключиться в командный режим (command mode), для чего в нормальном режиме следует ввести символ «двоеточие» — <kbd>:</kbd>

на изложенном и основывается упомянутая вами универсальная (т.е., не зависящая от текущего режима работы) мини-инструкция по «сохранению и выходу»:

- <kbd>esc</kbd> — из любого режима вернуться в нормальный
- <kbd>:</kbd> — переключиться в командный режим
- <kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> — выполнить команду `wq` («сохранить текущий буфер и закрыть его»)