# Как подтвердить действие в редакторе git?

Tags: git, git-commit

В Git потребовалось изменить название коммита. Новое название ввел с помощью insert. Что надо нажать, чтобы подтвердить ввод?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выйти из редактора Vi или Vim?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437417/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-vi-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-vim)

Comment: @RomanKonoval из того, что автор вопроса может не знать название запущенной им программы, никак не следует то, что с данной конкретной программой надо обращаться как-то по-особому (не так, как написано тысячи раз в интернетах). да ваш ответ это и подтверждает, собственно.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, `По-моему, не зная это найти ответ, который предлагается в качестве дубликата, на вопрос, который поставил автор, трудно.` — так зачем искать-то??? мы ведь уже и **дали подсказку**: данный вопрос — это о программе vim.