# Как закрыть терминал в intellij idea после git rebase?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-rebase

Пытаюсь слить два коммита в один в terminal'e `Intellij IDEA`.

1. git rebase -i HEAD~5
2. Изменил `pick` на `squash`

**Вопрос:** какими кнопками сохранить и выйти?

Скрин:

[image: Проблема, которая не закрывается в терминале]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выйти из редактора Vi или Vim?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437417/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-vi-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-vim)

Comment: @RomanKonoval не оно.

Comment: тогда показывайте скриншот, телепатия у нас развита, но хромает

Comment: @KoVadim прикрепил. Авось подскажите.

Comment: На скриншоте у вас vim, и вопрос дубликат.

Comment: @RomanKonoval нет не вим. Для того, чтобы был вим, нужно Settings-Plugins нажать кнопку `install`. А у меня в плагинах нет вима. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-product-as-the-vim-editor.html

Comment: похоже вим. @AndrewKachalin - Вы путаете  вим в редакторе и вим в кодсоли от гита. жмите два раза esc (для верности) потом двоеточие, w и потом enter

Comment: Просто двоеточие. Esc перебрасывает в другое окно. Только-то и всего.

Comment: ох эта idea... Лучше открыть в консоли отдельно и там все делать. Или открыть UI в IDEA, потянуть смузи и делать мышкой.

Answer (score 0):

> **ALT + F10**
>
> **CTRL + :**

```
:w - сохранить 
:q - выйти
```

:wq - Думаю понятно, что делает)