Удаление или редактирование сочетания клавиш nvim
У меня не стандартная раскладка клавиатуры, не QWERTY, а Workman. После смены раскладки пытаюсь настроить горячие клавиши, добавляю новые, но старые не удаляются, что делать?
Условно, как изменить сочетание клавиш yy для копирования строки на ff. И в целом поменять многие горячие клавиши, так как расположение букв на клавиатуре не стандартное.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/264178 может тут что найдете

https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+workman+layout
